# Are windows forms application are multiple instance supportive by default ? C#

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, winforms, instance

1. Are the normal winform applications in C# multiple instance support by default ?
2. How to prevent this creation of multiple instance in WPF applications ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1- Yes, you can execute many instance of your application. With some code, you can avoid it.

2- in App.xaml.cs, you can override some methods and use a Mutex :

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    private Mutex instanceMutex = null;

    protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        Boolean createdNew;
        this.instanceMutex = new Mutex(true, "MyApplication", out createdNew);
        if (!createdNew)
        {
            this.instanceMutex = null;
            Application.Current.Shutdown();
            return;
        }

        base.OnStartup(e);
    }

    protected override void OnExit(ExitEventArgs e)
    {
        if (this.instanceMutex != null)
        {
            this.instanceMutex.ReleaseMutex();
        }

        base.OnExit(e);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you Xaruth, this mutex need not be static ?

Comment: No need, it's like static for the system. Third parameter of the new ("out createdNew") give you if the Mutex is already exist or if it is a new (created by this instance of app).

Comment: Thank you again. Could you please explain this code in simple way, I am new to Mutex :(

Comment: Especially the Mutex line with 3 parameters I dont understand

Comment: Mutex is used for synchronization between threads, in order to avoid many acces to one resource. If Mutex is set, other threads wait for release of the Mutex. With this Method of new (3 parameters : Boolean, String, Boolean), you don't wait if you are not the owner, and you directly shutdown your app

Answer (score 2):

1. yes they are
2. see this [msdn article](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/csharpgeneral/thread/d7e9120a-f48a-4d3a-aaab-addc8eb6e0da/)

EDIT: or even better: [codeproject article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/84270/WPF-Single-Instance-Application)